# Shiny App deployment creates errors I've never seen before

Tags: r, shiny

New problem with shiny deployment:

I'm deploying from the Publish dropdown in Rstudio

I've never had a problem before, but now I get either this error

Hmm more details seem necessary but I'm not sure what they would be.

```
── Preparing for deployment ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔ Deploying "shiny_helper" to "server: shinyapps.io / username: cstangor"
ℹ Creating application on server...
Error in `POST()`:
! <https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/> failed with HTTP status
  409
Application exists with name: shiny_helper
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─rsconnect::deployApp(...)
 2.   └─client$createApplication(...)
 3.     └─rsconnect:::POST_JSON(service, authInfo, "/applications/", json)
 4.       └─rsconnect:::POST(...)
 5.         └─rsconnect:::httpRequestWithBody(...)
 6.           └─rsconnect:::handleResponse(httpResponse, error_call = error_call)
 7.             └─rsconnect (local) reportError(json$error)
 8.               └─cli::cli_abort(...)
 9.                 └─rlang::abort(...)
Execution halted

or this one:


── Preparing for deployment ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔ Re-deploying "shiny_helper" to "server: shinyapps.io / username: cstangor"
ℹ Looking up application with id "9627089"...
Error in `applicationDeleted()`:
! Failed to find existing application on server; it's probably been
  deleted.
ℹ Use `forgetDeployment()` to remove outdated record and try again.
ℹ Or use `applications()` to see other applications you have on the server.
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─rsconnect::deployApp(...)
 2.   └─base::tryCatch(...)
 3.     └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 4.       └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5.         └─value[[3L]](cond)
 6.           └─rsconnect:::applicationDeleted(client, target, recordPath, appMetadata)
 7.             └─rsconnect:::cli_menu(...)
 8.               └─cli::cli_abort(c(header, not_interactive), .envir = .envir, call = error_call)
 9.                 └─rlang::abort(...)
Execution halted
```

Comment: Have you tried the functions suggested in the error message: `applications()` to see what's deployed, or `forgetDeployment()` then trying again ?